# Crystal reports Query for subreport

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

| Task | User |
| --- | --- |
| Containment (Co User) | User1 |
| Disposition (Do User) | User2 |
| Investigation(Io User) | User3 |
| Approval (Ao User) | User4 |

I have the above data coming in preview of a sub-report, now I want to suppress any of this row based on a field that is available outside of this subreport. Consider this field as Taskname

Scenario1: If the field TaskName = 'Containment' then the output of the subreport should be like the below

| Task | User |
| --- | --- |
| Disposition (Do User) | User2 |
| Investigation(Io User) | User3 |
| Approval (Ao User) | User4 |

Scenario2: If the field TaskName = 'Disposition' then the output of the subreport should be like the below

| Task | User |
| --- | --- |
| Containment (Co User) | User1 |
| Investigation(Io User) | User3 |
| Approval (Ao User) | User4 |

I am unable to get any answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Pass the task from the main report as a ***subreport link***.
In the subreport, if you go into the
***Report, Selection Formula, Record...***
you would then see something like:

```
{SomeTable.Taks} = {?Pm-SomeTable.Taks}
```

Simply change it to:

```
{SomeTable.Taks} <> {?Pm-SomeTable.Taks}
```

Comment: The comparison value in the sub-report is not same as the one that will be passed. for eg; the values returned in the subreport is "Containment (Co User)" and the value in main report is "Containment".

Comment: No problem. Simply Follow the same logic when creating/editing the record selection formula in the subreport.

{Containment (Co User)} <> {?PM-Containment}